# Webfont Loader & Google JSAPI Cannot load together?

Tags: google-api, google-webfonts, jsapi, webfont-loader

I'm not sure why, though getting a similar issue.

Trying to load in a font from fonts.com with webfontloader so I can call functions after they're loaded.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js"></script>
<script>
   WebFont.load({
      monotype: {
        projectId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
      },
      active: function() {
         mainNav();
      }
   });
```

But when ever I include it WITH the jsapi

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

I get the following issue in the console:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'hasAttribute' of null

Yet if loaded in separately, they're fine...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the following url to load the webfonts api:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.1.2/webfont.js"></script>
```

Check the following post for more details: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-ajax-search-api/dWVzQF_YWCM/Y3-R738wh78J

> We no longer support partial version aliases for new versions of
>   libraries. Any partial version aliases already in place will continue
>   to be supported and updated. The reason is that URLs like
>   https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js
>   which is saying "give me the most recent version of jquery 1.x.x) have
>   very short cache lifetimes since the most recent version can change at
>   any time. This is bad for performance. This is also bad for your web
>   site, in the event that a library makes breaking changes in its APIs
>   between versions that cause your page to suddenly render differently.
>   Libraries do not usually make such changes intentionally but pages
>   sometimes depend on behavior of an unspecified corner case of an API
>   that may be changed intentionally or inadvertently as the library is
>   updated.
>
> So we strongly recommend that you specify the complete version string
>   when referencing libraries hosted on the Google AJAX APIs. You can
>   always find the most recent version at
>   https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide. In this case,
>   the most recent 1.9.x version is currently 1.9.1 so we suggest using
>   the URL
>   https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js
>   to get a stable version and better caching.

(Also, your example above doesn't have a closing `</script>` tag. Just want to verify this doesn't exist in your own code).